# Laravel : Get permissions list for a user through roles table with belongtomany

Tags: laravel

I have five tables to setup relationship between 3 tables are: 
+ users
+ roles
+ permissions

The relationship of users and roles are `many to many` through pivot table is "`user_role`"

The relationship of roles and permissions are also `many to many` through pivot table is "`role_permission`"

Now I want to display list users but I want bring their permissions on this list. How can I do that?

Name    Email            Role                   Permission

aaa     aa@gmail.com     Moderator, Customer    `create-post, update-post, delete-post`

Comment: Do you want to access to users permissions directly? Or you can access to it with roles?

Comment: @raminashrafimanesh I access with roles. But now I want list users has role is Moderator but I do not how to write condition

Answer (score 2):

**I have recently done this scenario by doing this way**

**User Model**

```
public function roles()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class,UserRole::class);
}
```

**Role Model**

```
public function permissions()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Permission::class,RolePermission::class);
}
```

***Now when you are getting all users you need to eager load your relationships***

```
public function index()
{
    $users = User::with('roles.permissions')->get();
               OR
    $users = User::with(['roles' => function($query){
                 $query->with('permissions');
             }])->get();
    return view('view_name',compact('users'));
}
```

**Note: You can also use laravel collections to reformat your roles and permissions collections for not using multiple loops. But I think you get the idea**

Comment: Hi @Akhtar: Thank you so much. I also found it. 
But do you know how to filter user by role id?

Comment: @HaiTien welcome, it depends on scenarios, like if you have a form for filtering and you are selecting only role id, then you need to use get request for that form ofcourse you will know it. Next You can do a `like` query inside user related roles means in a relationship.